# WPF ListView SelectedItem Binding Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, selecteditem

now i searched for 2 Days why my Binding does not work. I have a ListView inside a PopUp. I Want to bind the SelectedItem to the Code-Behind. I've done that 1298736 times before, but in this case it does not work.

Here is the Button that opens the Popup on Click:

```
<Button  ToolTip="Emoticon einfügen" Name="SmileImg" Click="SmileImg_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Image   Source="..\Smileys\Smile.png" Stretch="None" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ></Image>
</Button>
```

Here is the Popup definition

```
<Popup AllowsTransparency="True" Name="SmiliesPopup" PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=SmileImg}" StaysOpen="False" >
    <ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" BorderThickness="0" Name="EmoList" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSmile, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=FsRichTextBoxControl}" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Emoticons, ElementName=FsRichTextBoxControl}">

        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel MaxWidth="50" Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Width="16" Margin="2" Source="{Binding Uri}"></Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Popup>
```

So here is the Code:

```
public Emoticon SelectedSmile
{
  get { return m_selectedSmile; }
  set
  {
    if (m_selectedSmile == null)
    {
      m_selectedSmile = value;
    }
    else
    {
      if (value != null && EmoList.SelectedItem != null)
      {
        var emo = (Emoticon)EmoList.SelectedItem;
        InsertImage(new BitmapImage(emo.Uri));
        SmiliesPopup.IsOpen = false;
        EmoList.SelectedItem = null;
      }
      m_selectedSmile = value;
    }

    InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedSmile"));

  }
}
```

...

```
public RichtextBoxExt()
{
  Emoticons = new AsyncObservableCollection<Emoticon>
                {
                  new Emoticon("Smile", new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TeamNote;component/Smileys/Smile.png")),
                  new Emoticon("Cheeky", new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TeamNote;component/Smileys/Cheeky.png")),
                  new Emoticon("Cry", new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TeamNote;component/Smileys/Cry.png")),
                  new Emoticon("Kiss", new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TeamNote;component/Smileys/Kiss.png")),
                  new Emoticon("Wink", new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TeamNote;component/Smileys/Wink.png")),
                  new Emoticon("Sad", new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TeamNote;component/Smileys/Sad.png")),
                  new Emoticon("Laugh", new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TeamNote;component/Smileys/Laugh.png"))
                };
  SelectedSmile = new Emoticon("Smile", new Uri("pack://application:,,,/TeamNote;component/Smileys/Smile.png"));
  InitializeComponent();
  Initialize();
```

... and so on.

The ItemsSource Binding works well. Online SelectedItem does not work. SelectionChanged Event is also not firing.

PS:
This is just a prototype so please concentrate on the Problem and not on the style of programming :P

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE / Solution / Fixed ... whatever :P**

Thanks for all your answers. I found the reason why the selection does not Change at all ...

```
private void RichtextBoxExt_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //TextBox.Focus();
  Debug.WriteLine("RichtextBoxExt_GotFocus");
}
```

This eventhandler in the CodeBehind changes the focus everytime i clicked on an item and so the SelectedItem never changes.

Thanks for your thoughts !

Comment: `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSmile, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=FsRichTextBoxControl}`

this line is binding to a property `SelectedSmile` on element `FsRichTextBoxControl`. Im guessing this is not intentional?

Comment: @user1 this is correct ... FsRichTextBoxControl is the x:Name

Comment: So FsRichTextBoxControl has an attached property SelectedSmile? If that is the case I would look at your Binding Mode as others have said

Comment: correct me, but there is no need SelectedSmile to be an attached property (DependencyProperty), isnt it?. It is a normal property with backing field.

Comment: In this case you are binding to a SelectedSmile attached property on `FsRichTextBoxControl`. If However you would like to bind to the viewmodel property `SelectedSmile` I would advise. `"{Binding DataContext.SelectedSmile,  ElementName=FsRichTextBoxControl}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE / Solution / Fixed ... whatever :P**

Thanks for all your answers. I found the reason why the selection does not Change at all ...

```
private void RichtextBoxExt_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //TextBox.Focus();
  Debug.WriteLine("RichtextBoxExt_GotFocus");
}
```

This eventhandler in the CodeBehind changes the focus everytime i clicked on an item and so the SelectedItem never changes.

Thanks for your thoughts !

Answer (score 1):

Mode = OneWay  [OneWay updates the target property only when the source property changes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
  <ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" BorderThickness="0" Name="EmoList" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSmile, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=FsRichTextBoxControl}" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Emoticons, ElementName=FsRichTextBoxControl}" IsEnabled="False">
```

Use Mode = TwoWay.

Comment: thx for the hint :) but it still does not work. Changed it to TwoWay

Answer (score 1):

If your SelectedSmile Binding is `Mode=OneWay` your View(Model) will not getupdated on change.

Comment: thx for the hint :) but it still does not work. Changed it to TwoWay

Comment: So the Setter is not called at all?

Comment: Yes it is not called and the SelectionChanged Event does not fire. In runtime you can see that the first item is selected in the view. Clicking any other item does nothing

Comment: Nothing means: the selection does not change at all

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" BorderThickness="0" Name="EmoList" SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedSmile, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=FsRichTextBoxControl}" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Emoticons, ElementName=FsRichTextBoxControl}" IsEnabled="False">
```

I think this is where the error lay:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedSmile, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=FsRichTextBoxControl}"
```

Comment: This wont work because the property is not part of the DataContext. Because of this i used ElementName